# How to add data labels to seaborn pointplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

The code below creates a categorical plot with a pointplot on top of it, where the pointplot shows the mean and 95% confidence interval for each category. I need to add the mean data label to the plot, and I can't figure out how to do it.

FYI each category has thousands of points, so I don't want to label every datapoint, just the `estimator=np.mean` values in the point plot. Is this possible??

I've created a sample dataset here so you can copy and paste the code and run it yourself.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

d = {'SurfaceVersion': ['v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2', 'v3', 'v3', 'v3'],
        'Error%': [.01, .03, .15, .28, .39, .01, .01, .06, .09]}

df_comb =  pd.DataFrame(data=d)

plotHeight = 10
plotAspect = 2
 
#create catplot with jitter per surface version:
ax = sns.catplot(data=df_comb, x='SurfaceVersion', y='Error%', jitter=True, legend=False, zorder=1, height=plotHeight, aspect=plotAspect)
ax = sns.pointplot(data=df_comb, x='SurfaceVersion', y='Error%', estimator=np.mean, ci=95, capsize=.1, errwidth=1, hue='SurfaceVersion', color='k',zorder=2, height=plotHeight, aspect=plotAspect, join=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1.0))
plt.gca().legend().set_title('')
plt.grid(color='grey', which='major', axis='y', linestyle='--')
plt.xlabel('Surface Version')
plt.ylabel('Error %')
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, left=.05)
plt.suptitle('Error%')
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)                #This is to get rid of the legend that pops up with the seaborn plot b/c it's buggy.
plt.axhline(y=0, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-calculate the mean and add the labels in a loop. Bear in mind that x-values are really just 0, 1, 2 as far as positioning is concerned.

```
mean_df = df_comb.groupby("SurfaceVersion")[["Error%"]].mean()

for i, row in enumerate(mean_df.itertuples()):

    x_value, mean = row
    
    plt.annotate(
        round(mean, 2),               # label text
        (i, mean),                    # (x, y)
        textcoords="offset points",   
        xytext=(10, 0),               # (x, y) offset amount
        ha='left')
```

[image]